# What is the procedure to upload iOS app in app of the day

Tags: ios, app-store

I did some research but didn’t find anything in google.
I see apps which shows is app of the day in iOS AppStore. So how apple select this apps to show in app of the day? What is the precedure?

Comment: You pay them a lot of money or get really really lucky maybe.

Comment: Apple's editorial team select apps. Their criteria is not published and there is no procedure. They do seem to look for new, unusual, popular and well-presented apps that make the most of the Apple platform.  Supporting multiple languages and accessibility will probably help too.